# Kustomize configMapGenerator, render Helm chart, ArgoCd

Tags: argocd, kustomize

Is it possible to implement this behavior in ArgoCd?

I have a configMapGenerator:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
generators:
- helmgenerator.yaml

configurations:
- rollout-transform.yaml

configMapGenerator:
- name: dev-tw-info-app-props
  behavior: create
  files:
  - application.yaml=manifests/application.yaml
  - log4j2.properties=manifests/log4j2.properties
```

I would like to use helm functions in application.yaml for example, but Kustomization treats them as String.
Is it possible to somehow make configMapGenerator friendly with helm functions?

The option of generating charts with HelmChartInflationGenerator doesn't work for me.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible and I wouldn't even recommend it. It would be a pain for anyone to read and understand what's managed by Helm Vs what's by Kustomize. I love Kustomize but here why not just use Helm only?

Comment: Because I want to store Helm charts separately using, for example, a git submodule, and I need something that can connect the Helm templates and generate me a ConfigMap from application.yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow make configMapGenerator friendly with helm functions?

It is not. Kustomize is not a template processor and does not support things like variables, functions, etc. Kustomize operates by applying patches and other transformations to your manifests; possibly your desired configuration can be described using these facilities.

Kustomize does have support for [expanding Helm charts](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md). You can use Helm for templating your manifests and then use Kustomize transformations for changes that can't easily be described by your Helm templates.

In general, it's better to pick either Helm or Kustomize and stick with it.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem by moving the .yaml files to values.yaml and using HelmChartInflationGenerator